# How to run multiple test classes writing with Appium java-client in a maven project?

Tags: maven, testng, appium, android-testing

I wrote some Android UI tests maven project using appium java-client, testng, following Page Object Model. Basically:

- I have a class AppiumAndroidTest.java handles the set up and teardown, and every tests classes under Tests package is a subclass of AppiumAndroidTest.
- the @BeforeTest setUp() function in each subclass specify the desiredCapabilities(like, appActivity) then create new driver.
- below is my package architecture:

each test class succeed if I run them separately as "testNG test", but when I try to run the whole project as "Maven test", it will fail to create session. I am thinking maybe its because when running as "Maven test", it tries to run the 3 tests parallel, then the creation of session of some tests will fail cause other test class already created a session. Is this right? How can I handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry dont know why the image doesnt show up, but it shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: Try to set following capability as true  session-override  and in after test call driver.quit();

Comment: @shiv hi, thanks for your reply, I already add that, but it doesnt work, is it possible that I just have one server running and one simulator? Actually, is there any way I could make the test classes run sequentially?

Comment: Are you trying to run your test parallel on single device , if not please try to  put parallel= false in testng file

Comment: @shiv I added, still doesn't work, Appium tried to create another session(another test classes) and failed. don't know why...